# android upgrade to lollipop 5.1.1 have deleted all my data

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

i updated my nexus 4 two days ago. today at the afternoon, when i turned on the screen (shoer press), it seems like i turned on the phone at the first time. it asked me for my credit card, it showed me the new featurs etc. Unfortunately, when i finished complitting it I was amazed to discover that all the apps i had, gone. i have no idea what to do, but i belive google wouldn't delet all my apps without even warn me and not backup it. Thanks for answering.
p.m: if someone can edit my question and upgrade the english i'll be grateful.

Comment: I think such a question should be asked at http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thanks, do you think i should post it again there or there is a way to move it?

Comment: You may post there again (if not duplicated). This post might be closed if the moderators judge it is inappropriate here.